# HTC One Mini 2, lately the GPS apps have not been working

Tags: gps, htc-one

I have an HTC One Mini 2, lately the GPS apps have not been working.
It locates btwn 14 - 23 satellites, but it doesn't gt any FIX. 
Google Maps and Here Maps do not work well and locks at a position usually about 2kms away.
I have tried several GPS diagnosis apps on Play store, all I still get is NO FIX.
I also have set the GPS positioning mode to High Accuracy, all to no avail.

Help needed please.